# creating objects in js by using iffe vs constructor

Tags: javascript, iife

what is the difference between

```
var Student = (function () {
function Student(firstname, middleinitial, lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.middleinitial = middleinitial;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.fullname = firstname + " " + middleinitial + " " + lastname;
}
return Student;})();
```

vs

```
function Student(firstname, middleinitial, lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.middleinitial = middleinitial;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.fullname = firstname + " " + middleinitial + " " + lastname;
}
```

which one to use while creating a new object ?

```
var temp=new Student("john","R","wayne");
```

Comment: first one looks like a module that exports a class, second one looks like a class. Modules are meant more for 1 instance, classes many instances. 2nd method for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your IIFE does absolutely nothing but creating the `Student` function, it is exactly equivalent to

```
var Student = function Student(firstname, middleinitial, lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.middleinitial = middleinitial;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.fullname = firstname + " " + middleinitial + " " + lastname;
}
```

There's no reason to wrap this in an IIFE, as your are not introducing any local variables in the module scope.

So use the second snippet, it's two lines shorter and much clearer.